# CodeIgniter getting the most recently entered row from database and using it in controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and am trying to figure out how to enter data into a table (phone) that is related to another row of data in another related table (client). Right now, I think what I need to do is get the most recently created client row's id and assign it as the foreign key field of the phone table's row. So my question I am asking is how do I get that so that I can echo it on the screen, so that I can be sure it can be used for other purposes. I am trying to store the value of the client_id into a variable $client_id. But I get the following php error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: client_id

Filename: views/form_success.php

Line Number: 1

For reference purposes I am including my code WITHOUT changing names since this is NOT a commercial project but is supposed to simulate one.
MODEL

```
<?php

class insert_client extends CI_Model {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function form_insert($client_data) {
    // Insert Data into client table
    $this->db->insert('client', $client_data);
}

function get_id() {
    // Get id of most recently created record in client table.
    $this->db->select_max('client_id');
    $data = $this->db->get('client');
    return $data;
}
}
```

PART OF CONTROLLER (note the model is already loaded before the function in the code)

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('form_start');
        $this->load->view('client_form');
        $this->load->view('submit');
    } else {

        //CLIENT DATA
        $client_data = array (
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'apt_or_suite_number' => $this->input->post('apt_or_suite_number'),
            'zip_code' => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        );          

        // Get ID
        $client_id = $this->insert_client->get_id();

        // Transfer to models and store in database
        $this->insert_client->form_insert($client_data);

        // Load Success View
        $this->load->view('form_success', $client_id);
    }
```

AND SUCCESS MESSAGE (form_success)

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Client created! User ID = <?php echo ($client_id); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$this->db->insert_id()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html) function.

Model:

```
function form_insert($client_data) {
    // Insert Data into client table
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('client', $client_data);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $insert_id;
}
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('form_start');
        $this->load->view('client_form');
        $this->load->view('submit');
    } else {

        //CLIENT DATA
        $client_data = array (
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'apt_or_suite_number' => $this->input->post('apt_or_suite_number'),
            'zip_code' => $this->input->post('zip_code'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        );          

        // Transfer to models and store in database and get last inserted id
        $client_id = $this->insert_client->form_insert($client_data);

        // Load Success View
        $this->load->view('form_success', $client_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with getting the data:

```
function get_id() {
    // Get id of most recently created record in client table.
    $this->db->select_max('client_id');
    $query = $this->db->get('client');
    $data = $query->result();

/* or
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->title;
    }
*/

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you put title in the echo, nor why you are echoing in a model.

Comment: the point is, that you need to fetch the $data with $query->result(). $data contains $rows, each row has fields like title, that's just the example from the user_guide.

Comment: I see, so what if I want to use it in my controller? You see I tried your solution and now I am dealing with a array to string conversion issue.

Comment: Don't worry, I just used a count of the rows for now. I think I am not explaining what I need well enough to be understood on here. But that is the simplest solution for right now.